# Are there any tools to have an SVN server save the comment log into an SQL database?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnserve, svn-server

I'm curious if there are any open-source tools so an SVN server (such as VisualSVN) can be configured to maintain the comment log in an SQL database (such as MySQL).

I'm only interested in storing the repository name, revision number, and associated user comment for every commit. Ideally I would like the comment log to be maintained automatically, so any changes to the database and/or the SVN repository are synchronized (assuming that all changes are legal in both contexts).

As a first order approach one could write a post-commit script to store the commit comment into the SQL database, but I am looking for more than that.

Comment: A post-commit hook *is* the method to do it. The only other option is some kind of tool (like a CI system) monitoring the server, pulling the log, and taking action from there. But a hook script is a far more elegant solution.

Comment: @alroc Thanks for the reply. The post-commit hook sounds like the only viable method, but it is good to have that confirmed.

Comment: Fantastic idea! I have made quite good use of the post-commit hook to do per revision dumps and email notifications, but an update of a SQL DB makes good sense! Especially in the case where one can rather run daily / weekly reports on commits, and thus avoid spam email.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this question is now obsolete. Modern VisualSVN Server versions have a modern repository web interface and it supports viewing revision logs.

Try it on the demo server at https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/history.

[image]

Comment: The goal was not to provide a method for users to browse the revisions log. Granted you could parse that webpage with a script and store the information into a database.